# In scala how to determine whether a class object implements a trait

Tags: scala, reflection

It is something as the code below. I found `isAssignableFrom` in Java but it's not in scala.

```
  trait A

  def isTraitA(c:Class[_]) = {
    // check if c implements A
    // something like 
    // classOf[A].isAssignableFrom(c) 
  }
  
  isTraitA(this.getClass)
```

Comment: Well, **Java** reflection works for **Scala** too, so it probably should work. - However, runtime reflection is generally avoided in **Scala** and considered a bad practice _(because, it is unsafe, insecure, slow and non-portable)_; unless you are 100% sure this is the best way to solve your problem, I would recommend you to explain what is the meta-problem that lead you to this solution, there is probably a _better_ alternative.

Comment: Java reflection works for Scala, as long as you are running on a JVM. I would not bet on Java reflection working with Scala.js, Scala-native, or any other potential platform (such as the dormant Scala.NET). It is quite unfortunate that so many Scala programmers tie their programs so closely to Java that every alternative platform (e.g. Scala.js, Scala-native, Scala.NET) has to re-implement large part of the JRE over and over again. (Scala.NET even eventually resorted to running a full JVM on top of the CLR.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, that is exactly what I mean with _"non-portable"_. Also, I would say that the stdlib library is also responsible for this, the absence of good replacements for things like `java.nio` and `java.time` _(that may be just simple wrappers when running on the JVM)_ imply that things like **ScalaJS** and **Native** have to patch those. Finally, I must say that is unfortunate that things like **Tasty** that were supposed to help different distributions of **Scala** couldn't provide enough information for **ScalaJS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments said you can use Java reflection but this ties you to JVM.

If you wanted to use Scala's reflection you can do something like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def isTraitA[B: TypeTag]: Boolean = typeOf[B] <:< typeOf[A]
```

You could then try in REPL that:

```
class C
class D extends A

isTraitA[C] // false
isTraitA[D] // true
```

The difference is that you have to pass implicit `TypeTag[B]` for your type `B` all the way through from where it is known (so e.g. add `: TypeTag` after type parameter every time the type is defined as parameter) and it has to be known at some point (so you cannot simple ask for an instance of `TypeTag` when you only know a `String` with a canonical name of the type).

Comment: Nice, thanks!
Alternatively: ```def isTrait_A_conforming_to_B[A: TypeTag, B: TypeTag]: Boolean = typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[B]```

Comment: Well, yes, but instead of writing `isTrait_A_conforming_to_B[X, Y]` you could write `typeOf[X] <:< typeOf[Y]` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question works just fine:

```
scala 2.13.4> trait A
trait A

scala 2.13.4> def isTraitA(c:Class[_]) = classOf[A].isAssignableFrom(c)
def isTraitA(c: Class[_]): Boolean

scala 2.13.4> isTraitA(classOf[A])
val res0: Boolean = true

scala 2.13.4> isTraitA(classOf[AnyRef])
val res1: Boolean = false

scala 2.13.4> isTraitA((new AnyRef with A).getClass)
val res2: Boolean = true
```

What led you to believe it doesn't work?